# Error when I tried to assign a value in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an object in angular:

```
export class Task {
  taskId: number;
  description: string;
  date: string;
  project: Project;
}
```

And in a component, I want to have a method that adds a new task. And for this I created a component:

```
export class CreateNewTaskComponent implements OnInit {

  task: Task = new Task();
  projectName: string;
  newTask: Task = new Task();

  constructor(
    private taskService: TaskService,
    private projectService: ProjectService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  addANewTask() {
    this.projectService.getProjectByProjectName(this.projectName).subscribe(
      (project) => {
        this.project = project;
        console.log('Project: ' + JSON.stringify(this.project));
      }
    );

    this.newTask.description = this.task.description;
    this.newTask.date = this.task.date;
    this.newTask.project = this.project;

    this.taskService.createNewTask(this.newTask).subscribe(
      task => {
        console.log(task);
        this.router.navigate(['/tasks']);
      });
  }
```

I have created a Project object based on the project name. When I did **console.log('Project: ' + JSON.stringify(this.project));** I received the correct answer. But when I tried to assign the project to a new task  **this.newTask.project = this.project;** the result is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Project is not defined in your component, but you are not getting that error so I am assuming it is just missing here

```
export class CreateNewTaskComponent implements OnInit {

 task: Task = new Task();
 projectName: string;
 newTask: Task = new Task();

 constructor(
   private taskService: TaskService,
   private projectService: ProjectService,
   private router: Router) {
 }

 addANewTask() {
   this.projectService.getProjectByProjectName(this.projectName).subscribe(
     (project) => {
       this.project = project;
       console.log('Project: ' + JSON.stringify(this.project));
// this should be inside subscribe and not outside 
// it is async so might be executed after the lines outside
       this.newTask.project = this.project;
     }
   );

   //this.newTask.description = this.task.description;
   //this.newTask.date = this.task.date;
  // this.newTask.project = this.project;

   this.taskService.createNewTask(this.newTask).subscribe(
     task => {
       console.log(task);
// these should be here
this.newTask.description = this.task.description;
  this.newTask.date = this.task.date;
       this.router.navigate(['/tasks']);
     });
 }
```

the assignment should be inside subscribe, I have updated code with some comments

Answer (score 1):

Because `this.newTaskProject = this.project` operation happens before `this.project = project;` which is in subscribe.

You can consider this:

```js
addANewTask() {
    this.projectService
        .getProjectByProjectName(this.projectName)
        .pipe(
            switchMap(project => {
                this.newTask.description = this.task.description;
                this.newTask.date = this.task.date;
                this.newTask.project = project;

                return this.taskService.createNewTask(this.newTask);
            })
        )
        .subscribe(task => {
            console.log(task);
            this.router.navigate(['/tasks']);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Actions in subscribe are asynchronous therefore you have to place all the subsequent operations in the success response of the service as well.

Project variable is also not defined in the component so you can't use this.project either.

```
    addANewTask() {
        this.projectService.getProjectByProjectName(this.projectName).subscribe(
          (project) => {
            console.log('Project: ' + JSON.stringify(project));

            this.newTask.description = this.task.description;
            this.newTask.date = this.task.date;
            this.newTask.project = project;

            this.taskService.createNewTask(this.newTask).subscribe(
             task => {
               console.log(task);
              this.router.navigate(['/tasks']);
             });
          }
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to async program and result. Your code is not correct, try in this way:

```
addANewTask() {
    this.projectService.getProjectByProjectName(this.projectName).subscribe(
      (project) => {


    this.newTask.description = this.task.description;
    this.newTask.date = this.task.date;
    this.newTask.project = project;

    this.taskService.createNewTask(this.newTask).subscribe(
      task => {
        console.log(task);
        this.router.navigate(['/tasks']);
      });
      }
    );

  }
```

Now it must be work